# adapting collapsible checkbox tree plugin for radio buttons

Tags: jquery, plugins, checkbox, nested, radio-button

I'm making use of [Red Carrot's Checkbox Tree plugin](http://www.redcarrot.co.uk/2009/11/11/collapsible-checkbox-tree-jquery-plugin/) but trying to adapt it to use with a nested list of radio buttons.

Replacing all references to ‘checkbox’ with ‘radio’ works for the most part, but the uncheckChildren option does not work – When selecting a different parent option, the first selected parent is deselected (as you would rightly expect with radio buttons!) but any children of the deselected parent remain selected, and the list does not collapse. This is less than ideal, as it means the user can select a child of an unselected parent.
Can anyone suggest what I might need to change in the script to achieve the same behaviour as with checkboxes (though retaining radio button behaviour of single selection allowed at each level)?

Comment: Trying to find questions I can actually make a useful contribution to..a reflection of how green I am. Will try harder! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Jquery DynaTree Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/)